# How to adjust number rows in HTML table based on window size and swap data at timed intervals?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of tuples that I would like to display in a table. If there are more tuples than would fit in the window, I would like to cut the table short and only display that many tuples (rows), and then swap the data out at periodic intervals (allowing the data to be shown on a projector screen for example).

I can monkey around with Javascript enough to do this if I knew where to start, but I don't have much experience programming in the browser. i.e. I'm not even sure where to start looking.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tabe width and row width as percentage like,

```
<table width='100%'>
  <tr>
     <td width='10%'></td>
     ..................
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that just make the table width equal to the width of the window. What I want is if the screen can accommodate 20 rows (or however many), to have 20 rows in the able and then start changing the data periodically.

Comment: If 20 rows then use, <td width='5%'></td>